# Update and delete specific row CSV file using Java

Tags: java

I have this code to save and read my data in the CSV file. I want to update and also delete a specific cell (based on 'code') in those CSV files. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Database {
  //DISPLAY MENU FROM CSV FILE
  public static ArrayList<FoodeliverMenu> readFoodeliverMenuFromFile() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<FoodeliverMenu> menu = new ArrayList<>();

    // read menu.csv into a list of lines.
    Path menu_path = Paths.get("menu.csv");
    try {
      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(menu_path);
      Collections.sort(lines);

      for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { //0 is from ArrayList
        // split a line by comma
        String[] items = lines.get(i).split(",");
        // items[0] is code, items[1] is name, items[2] is price
        int code = Integer.parseInt(items[0]);
        double price = Double.parseDouble(items[2]);
        menu.add (new FoodeliverMenu(code, items[1], price));

        System.out.println(code + " " + items[1] + " $" + price + "0");
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File " + menu_path + " is not found!");
      }return menu;
  }

  public static void saveFoodeliverMenuToFile(ArrayList<FoodeliverMenu> menu) throws IOException {
    // read menu.csv into a list of lines.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
      sb.append (menu.get(i).toCSVString() + "\n");
    }
    Files.write(Paths.get("menu.csv"), sb.toString().getBytes());
  }  
}
```

Comment: hm, can't see another reasonable way than to re-write the whole file. There might be a odbc driver for csv, though. But why not use a slim database for this usage pattern?

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish in relation to your question is a bit clouded by the fact that the first thing that you're doing is sorting based on the value of the string representation of the entire row. Is this the case, or do you really want to sort the list based on item code? Will the item codes be unique? Take a look at SortedList and SortedSet types.

Comment: I would also say that CSV applies more to data IMPORT (as in is someone or some other system is creating your initial CSV?), that or you're trying to leverage CSV to enable interoperability with spreadsheet users? If that is the case, then CSV has no implied data types, uniqueness, order, etc. so even if you're dealing with presorted rows you can't assume that you'll just be inserting a new row between sorted rows.